# Omitting "xsd:" prefix in WSDL type definitions

Tags: xml, xsd, wsdl

I have a WSDL file that includes (ie. refers to) two .xsd files for type definitions. Unfortunately our system that parses the WSDL file cannot handle such includes, so I need to create one monolith WSDL file.

So I copy & pasted all `<simpleType>` and `<complexType>` definitions from the .xsd files into the WSDL file. Now when I try to parse that large WSDL file I get the error message that `simpleType` is not a valid WSDL-1.1 element.

I guess the solution to this problem would be to prefix all these copied definition tags with `xsd:`, right? However, that would be a very cumbersome work, as we have dozen of such definitions in these two .xsd files.

So my question is: Can I wrap all the definitons I have copied somehow in the WSDL file, so that I can omit the `xsd:` prefix?

Comment: I would try this: change the default namespace to xsd namespace and prefix all wsdl element tags with wsdl namespace

Comment: maybe it is sufficient to change the default namespace for the `<types>` element and redefine it as `<wsdl:types xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/">`

Comment: btw. it is funny you do not use explicit `xsd:` or `xs:` namespaces in your xsd files (never seen that approach)

Comment: @PavelGatnar: It's not our WSDL+XSD, but from an external provider.. I will have a look into your suggestions though, thanks.

Comment: other possibility is to replace all XSD tags with prefixed tags using regular expressions

Comment: Yeah, I ended up no with simply replacing all tags in the text editor. Thought there would be a more elegant solution to this though :)

Comment: you do not have to do it manually, don't you?

Comment: what about this? https://github.com/lenardg/WSDLMerge

Comment: Yes, but the tool didn't work for me in the first place, so I ended up search&replacing those tags. Didn't took me too long...